# Jenkins downstram by success percentage

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline

I have jenkins deployment process that uses Ansible playbook for deployment, sometimes that job runs on 100 hosts.
I have a downstream job that runs on a successful run of the deployment job.

If 1 host is failed for some reason, it fails all the deployment and the downstream is not running, I want to mark the deployment job as a successful run even if 10% of the hosts are failed.
How can I achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use, as the documenatation of the [meta](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/meta_module.html?highlight=clear_host_errors) module states

```
- meta: clear_host_errors
```

as the last task in your playbook. This will clear all errors from failed hosts. Additionally you can deal with the [Maximum Failure Percentage](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#maximum-failure-percentage).

```
max_fail_percentage: 10
```

Put it all together in a play:

```
- hosts: my_host_group
  max_fail_percentage: 10

  tasks:

  - name: "Do something"
    command: "uname -a"

  - name: "Do something other"
    command: "id -a"

  - meta: clear_host_errors
```

Comment: Thanks @jgk but I don't want to mark the job as successful if 90% are failed.

Comment: yes, they both seem related, sorry for the noob question how do I make them work in the following way:
If there's more than 10% failed hosts ), fail the job- (max_fail_percentage: 10

else mark the job as a success (- meta: clear_host_errors)